# Trigger MediaElements Player to Start Playing

Tags: mediaelement.js

WE are working toward running audio along side Galleria Slide shows. Galleria (js-json-html slideshow framework) does not, by itself, support sound, but you can trigger other functions from events in Galleria. We use MediaElement player for our sound and we can trigger the instantiation of a player controller when the user first interacts with the slideshow to move to the second slide.

But I am unable to get the player to start. In theory my code below is correct and I am not getting any errors in FireBug. the "mePlayer.play()" call is, I think supposed to initiate playback. But it is not... any one have an idea why?

```
$("#gallery1360896922").galleria({
    dataSource: data,
    height: 500,
      width: 809,
      imageCrop:'landscape',
      thumbcrop: false,
     _showFullscreen: false,
      imagePan:true,
      idleMode:false,
      transitionSpeed:150});   

Galleria.on('loadfinish',function(e){

if (e.index==1){
       var mePlayer = $('#audio-').mediaelementplayer
          ({
       features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','volume'],
       audioWidth:809,
});

mePlayer.play();
}
});
```

All the above works, almost see:

http://www.himalayanacademy.com/blog/taka/2012/02/17/test-media-player-with-slide-show/

and click to move to the second slide.. voila! mediaelement player appears, but will not start.

Answer (score 0):

For starters try to instantiate your mediaelement object when **document.ready**.

Define a global scope variable in which you will assign the instantiation of the object:

```
var mePlayer; //Global scope variable


mePlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#audio-', //...and so on
```

Then, on any event you do `mePlayer .play();`